# Tagging custom environments like equations

Tags: equations, environments, counters, labels

I'm trying to tag a set of custom environments in the same way I've tagged a set of equations as in the output below. i.e. I'd like "Reaction 1" to display in the same way as "Equation 1" at the end of the line.

[image]

I've managed to label the environments correctly with a counter, and they are correctly referenced in the block text. However, I'm unable to find a way to display the tag at the end of the output line. I'm new to LATEX so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Input is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand\theequation{Equation\,\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

%%%%%%%%%%PROBLEM INPUT
\newcounter{reaction}
\renewcommand\thereaction{Reaction\,\arabic{reaction}}
\setcounter{reaction}{0}
\newenvironment{reaction}[1][]{\refstepcounter{reaction}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

The general formula for the curative needed is given by 

\ref{RequiredCurative}. 
\begin{equation}\label{RequiredCurative} a = b + c\end{equation} \par 
A generic curing reaction as described above is shown in \ref{Curing} below.\medskip 
\begin{flushleft}\begin{reaction}\label{Curing}\chemfig{A-B -> C-D}\end{reaction}\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does your reaction environment have only one line? It is quite easy then. By the way, your reaction environment definition is missing the `{}` code statement.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, only one line for the foreseeable cases

Comment: \hfill will generally overpower things like flushleft, flushright and center.  It expands to fill all the unused space in a line.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `numberedblock` package: http://ctan.org/pkg/numberedblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only one line 'reaction' required, it is sufficient to put the numbering in the end code of the `reaction` environment. The end code has been missing in the O.P., however.

The macro `\reactionfmt` is wrapper for easier change of formatting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand\theequation{Equation\,\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

%%%%%%%%%%PROBLEM INPUT
\newcounter{reaction}
\renewcommand\thereaction{Reaction\,\arabic{reaction}}
\setcounter{reaction}{0}
\newenvironment{reaction}[1][]{\refstepcounter{reaction}}{\hfill\reactionfmt}

\newcommand{\reactionfmt}{(\thereaction)}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

The general formula for the curative needed is given by 

\ref{RequiredCurative}. 
\begin{equation}\label{RequiredCurative} a = b + c\end{equation} \par 
A generic curing reaction as described above is shown in \ref{Curing} below.\medskip 
%\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{reaction}\label{Curing}
    \chemfig{A-B -> C-D}
  \end{reaction}
%\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]